# IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=LwAt/lbcRvuggC8Tnzeh0Q==) Vendor code 17002

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Not able to connect my oracle connection

I recently install the oracle sql developer and creating the connection but it is not opening the connection and showing (An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=LwAt/lbcRvuggC8Tnzeh0Q==)

Vendor code 17002) this error.

Comment: It's not enough to just install Oracle SQL Developer. That's your client. You need a database (server) to connect to. I have advice here https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2021/02/im-a-student-studying-oracle-and-i-need-a-database-help/